# Changing Team-> Remote-> Upstream URI in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I update the URI of remote Git repository for a project in the workspace, the other projects' URI is also being updated.  Each project should have has its own Git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse a project is a folder on the filesystem that contains a `.project` resource (meta-file that describes the project, hidden by default in eclipse in the Java package explorer for example, but that can be seen in the `Navigator` view).

A git repository that is cloned on your file system has a root folder (in which you will find the `.git` folder). Your git repository probably contains several eclipse projects (in sub folders) that you have imported in your eclipse workspace.

Check your projects locations (project properties > project path) and you will see that they all reside in the same git tree.

If you change the upstream URI of your git repository, it applies to the whole repository. It cannot be applied only on a given sub folder of the tree.

So, when you right click on a project and change a Git setting (like the git URI), it applies on the whole Git repository. And as a consequence, it applies on all Eclipse projects that belong to the same git repository.

What is confusing I guess is that when you right click on a project to change its settings, you expect to change something that will only apply to that Eclipse project. This is true for most Eclipse preferences, but not for Git (because of what is explained above).

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was the missing element.